# Default timeout of curl call using libcurl in c++

Tags: c++, libcurl

My application(A) in c++ makes curl call to another machine to start another application(B). When curl call is made by A then it waits till B finishes it's job. So I just want to ask that what is the default timeout for application A or it is by default disables i.e infinite timeout ?

Answer (score 14):

From http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

> [CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCONNECTTIMEOUT)
>
> Pass a long. It should contain the maximum time
>   in seconds that you allow the connection  to the server to take. This
>   only limits the connection phase, once it has connected, this option
>   is of no more use. Set to zero to switch to the default built-in
>   connection timeout - 300 seconds. See also the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option.

.

> [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTTIMEOUT)
>
> Pass a long as parameter containing the maximum time in seconds that
>   you allow the libcurl transfer operation to take. Normally, name
>   lookups can take a considerable time and limiting operations to less
>   than a few minutes risk aborting perfectly normal operations. This
>   option will cause curl to use the SIGALRM to enable time-outing system
>   calls.
>
> In unix-like systems, this might cause signals to be used unless
>   CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL is set.
>
> **Default timeout is 0 (zero) which means it never times out.**

Comment: Thank you , just to be clear I am asking one more question. I am using curl_easy_setopt(request,CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com") in my code , so technically this will never expire and will wait for response from application B on other machine.

Comment: In that line you're just letting `libcurl` know about the URL to be talked to later on, no request will be sent before a `curl_easy_perform()` call. And you should accept this answer.